# list files by symlink target

Tags: find, symlink

How do I get list of files (and then do something with that list) by filtering through the symbolic link *target* name, and not the symlink name? For example from the following list I'm only interested in the first four files (target contains `bar`):

```
foo ->  /tmp/bar
bar ->  /home/me/bartoo
baz ->  /home/me/public/barthree
zoo ->  /usr/share/bar
moo ->  /tmp/foo
roc ->  /tmp/roc
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use find to fetch all files of type symlink and add the `-ilname` option to search by name of the link destination. This works just like `-iname` but for the link target name instead of the link name.

```
find -type l -ilname "*bar*"
```

That will still print out the name of the link, not the target. If you want to print the names of the targets, try this:

```
find -type l -ilname "*bar*" -printf "%l\n"
```

Or get a full `ls` style output

```
find -type l -ilname "*bar*" -ls
```

---

What you mean by "*do something with the list*" is unclear, but if you wanted to operate on the link files, you could use the `-exec` argument to find:

```
find -type l -ilname "*bar*" -exec touch {} \;
```

But if you need to operate on the link targets, you will need to use the `-printf` to get the target values and then `xargs` or some loop yourself to operate. You could do something like this:

```
find -type l -printf "%l\n" | grep bar | xargs touch
```

... which also demonstrates how to use `grep` instead of `find -ilname` to do your name matching, although you could do that either way.

Comment: thank you Caleb! You completely answered my immediate question as well as covering some side channel cases which I will definitely use also.

Comment: any idea why this `find /dev/disk/ -type l -ilname "*sde*"` doesnt work?

Comment: Requires GNU find.